# How to pass value from NSViewController to custom NSView of NSPopover?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview, delegation, nsviewcontroller

By using the delegation protocol I have tried to pass a string (**inputFromUser.string**) from NSViewController - **mainController** to custom subclass of NSView of NSPopover - **PlasmidMapView**, to drawRect function, see code below. But, it didn’t work. I don’t know where a mistake is. Maybe there is another way to pass this string.

**Update**

File 1.

```
  protocol PlasmidMapDelegate {
    func giveDataForPLasmidMap(dna: String)
  }

  class MainController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var inputFromUser: NSTextView!
    var delegate: plasmidMapDelegate?

    @IBAction func actionPopoverPlasmidMap(sender: AnyObject) {
         popoverPlasmidMap.showRelativeToRect(sender.bounds, 
             ofView: sender as! NSView, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.MinY)

         let dna = inputDnaFromUser.string
         delegate?.giveDataForPLasmidMap(dna!)  
    }
}
```

File 2

```
class PlasmidMapView: NSView, PlasmidMapDelegate {

    var dnaForMap = String()

    func giveDataForPLasmidMap(dna: String) {
        dnaForMap = dna
    }       

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {

    let objectOfMainController = MainController()
    objectOfMainController.delegate = self

        //here I have checked if the string dnaForMap is passed
         let lengthOfString = CGFloat(dnaForMap.characters.count / 10)

         let pathRect = NSInsetRect(self.bounds, 10, 45)
         let path = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: pathRect, 
             xRadius: 5, yRadius: 5)
         path.lineWidth = lengthOfString //the thickness of the line should vary in dependence on the number of typed letter in the NSTextView window - inputDnaFromUser
         NSColor.lightGrayColor().setStroke()
         path.stroke()
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there's some architecture mistakes. You don't need delegate method and protocol at all. All you just need is well defined setter method:

I. Place your `PlasmidMapView` into `NSViewController`-subclass. This view controller must be set as `contentViewController`-property of your `NSPopover`-control. Don't forget to set it the way you need in `viewDidLoad`-method or another.

```
class PlasmidMapController : NSViewController {
    weak var mapView: PlacmidMapView!
}
```

II. In your `PlacmidMapView` don't forget to call `needsDisplay`-method on `dna` did set:

```
class PlasmidMapView: NSView {
    //...
    var dnaForMap = String() {
        didSet {
            needsDisplay()
        }
    //...
}
```

III. Set `dna`-string whenever you need from your `MainController`-class.

```
@IBAction func actionPopoverPlasmidMap(sender: AnyObject) {
     popoverPlasmidMap.showRelativeToRect(sender.bounds, 
         ofView: sender as! NSView, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.MinY)

     let dna = inputDnaFromUser.string
     if let controller = popoverPlasmidMap.contentViewController as? PlasmidMapController {
         controller.mapView.dna = dna
     } else {
         fatalError("Invalid popover content view controller")
     }
}
```

Comment: One thing is unclear for (I am beginner) - "Don't forget to set it the way you need in viewDidLoad-method or another". Could you explain?

Comment: @VYT you need to initialize the mapView object, add to the NSViewController view, set autolayout constraints maybe, etc.

Comment: Finally!!! I have played around with what you suggested and found a simple solution. It is not exactly what you suggested but you gave me an idea, and I give you the bounty. Thanks again!

Comment: @VYT if my answer did help you check it as correct please.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use delegation your class **PlasmidMapView** needs to have an instance of the **MainController** (btw name convention is Class, not class) and conform to the **PlasmidMapDelegate** (once again name convention dictates that it should be PlasmidMapDelegate). With that instance you then can:

`mainController.delegate = self`

Comment: If I place mainController.delegate = self in PlasmidMapView class I have complain - Expected Declaration.

Comment: Is PlasmidMapView a subView of the MainController?

Comment: No, it is NSView of NSPopover

Answer (score 1):

So, after several days I have found a solution without any protocols and delegation as Astoria has mentioned. All what I needed to do was to make `@IBOutlet var plasmidMapIBOutlet: PlasmidMapView!`for my custom NSView in **MainController** class and then to use it to set the value for the **dnaForMap** in  `@IBAction func actionPopoverPlasmidMap(sender: AnyObject)`.

```
class PlasmidMapView: NSView
{
    var dnaForMap = String()
}

class MainController: NSViewController 
{
    @IBOutlet var inputFromUser: NSTextView!
    @IBOutlet var plasmidMapIBOutlet: PlasmidMapView!      

     @IBAction func actionPopoverPlasmidMap(sender: AnyObject) 
    {
         plasmidMapIBOutlet.dnaForMap = inputDnaFromUser.string!  

         popoverPlasmidMap.showRelativeToRect(sender.bounds, 
         ofView: sender as! NSView, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.MinY)         
    }
}
```